# Can you set the distance between letter in a font with itextsharp c#

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

Can you set the distance between two letter for the font in iTextsharp? I am needing to fill in a form like pdf that has blocks where my text need to go?

Comment: Do you mean CharacterSpacing?

Comment: Yes I think so I need to have more space between the different characters in each word

Comment: Are you filling a actual PDF-form? If this is the case, you can access those fields directly instead of stamping over the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try it with the following Method:

```
private Chunk GetChunk(string text)
    {
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(text);
        chunk.SetCharacterSpacing(YourSpacingHere);
        return chunk;
    }
```

If that doesnt fit your needs, please provide some code